# I am adding a JPanel to a JLayeredPane and can't get the background transparent

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, transparency, jlayeredpane

I am writing a game in java. In the main UI I have the game map being rendered on a canvas, I add that canvas to a JLayeredPane which is working fine. Then I add a player portrait area over the top of that near the top of the screen. The Player portrait area is a JPanel, the problem is I can't get the background of that portrait area to be transparent. It always has a white background.

I have tried setting the portraitArea JPanel setOpaque("false") that doesn't seem to have an affect. I also tried adding a background color with alpha and that doesn't make a difference either.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: I am trying this on 6.

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html).

Comment: Here are a few important snippets of the code that I am using.
`JLayeredPane pane = new JLayeredPane();
pane.add(game, 1, 0);
portraitArea = new PortraitArea();
portraitArea.setOpaque(false);
pane.add(portraitArea, 2, 0);
portraitArea.setBackground(new Color(255,0,0,0));
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);`

Comment: sorry I am new to posting on here all of the formatting was removed from that comment is there a better way to post the code?

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work? Because I have similar problem now :)
And to answer your question: better way is editing your question - there you can format code.